# How to set different values for dynamic select in reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on dynamic select using reactive form. Dynamic select with the same values are working fine. But I have a requirement of loading the dropdown values dynamically.

```js
  public getFoodByCategory(type: string) {
    const res = this.data.find(d => d.type === type);
    if (res) {
      return res.options;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

```html
<h4> SELECT CATEGORY:  </h4>

<select multiple (change)="categorySelect($event)" formControlName="category">
        <option [value]="item.name" *ngFor="let item of category">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>

<h4> DROP-DOWN VALUE BASED ON CATEGORY SELECTION ?  </h4>   
<div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of form.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
 <div [formGroupName]="i">
  {{ form.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name.value | uppercase }}
    <select formControlName="favorite">
            
==>    <!-- defaultOrders values should be dynamically load from service (this.datasourceService.getFoodByCategory(type)) -->
                
      <option *ngFor="let order of defaultOrders; let i = index" [value]="order.name">
        {{order.name}}
      </option>
      </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

The expected is, when the category is selected as **starter**, the values inside the dropdown should be `Starter - A, Starter - B, Starter - C`. If multiple category select then dropdown should be loaded based on respective type.

***Expectation*:**

[image: result]

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7j8sr)

***Is there any better solution?***

> **EDITED**

I found a workaround for my issue briefed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57706819/3690766).

Please do share if there is any better solution.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? In stackblitz, it behaves fine by selecting starter, it shows the starter - A, starter - B and started - C and if we select both starter and deserts, the dynamic dropdown showing the perfect list.

Comment: Partially Yes! I tried a solution like calling a method inside options. i.e., instead of a fixed array call a method to return an array. But it triggers another issue. It calls for each and every click. Check the console in the stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue with 2 solutions:

1. Use a method to construct an array(based on condition).
2. Use pipe (bind array and filter based on condition)

Solution 1: Method
`(getItemsByName(form.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name.value)` inside `*ngFor`.

```
<select formControlName="favorite">
  <option *ngFor="let order of getItemsByName(form.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name.value); let i = index" [value]="order.name">
       {{order.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Solution 2: Pipe

```
<select formControlName="favorite">
  <option *ngFor="let order of categoryItems | filterItem: form.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name.value; let i = index" [value]="order.name">
    {{order.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

The 1st solution creates a performance issue. The method calls 2 times whenever dropdown is open and close.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7j8sr)